# Retreive API response data with cy.intercept

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm intercepting request URL: https://api-stg.geneplanet.com/api/nipt-exporters/tasks/407ff05afdec42caa17a660d2c855117/status
Response of requested URL is

```js
{
  "name": "ExportN2DStatisticsOrchestrator",
  "instanceId": "407ff05afdec42caa17a660d2c855117",
  "runtimeStatus": "Completed",
  "input": {
  "BlobUri": "https://niptexportersstgsa.blob.core.windows.net/nipt-exports/N2D statistics 
  export_11.04.2022 13.38.49.xlsx?sv=2018-03- 
  28&sr=c&sig=V0pXmIQUccUdkm0WtsZ3ENjfr%2FtYiCvYDztgZ6JWaYk%3D&se=2022-04- 
  11T12%3A38%3A49Z&sp=rc",
  "From": "2022-03-11T00:00:00+00:00",
  "To": "2022-04-11T23:59:59+00:00"
  },
  "customStatus": {
    "message": "done"
  },
  "output": null,
  "createdTime": "2022-04-11T11:38:49Z",
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2022-04-11T11:38:50Z"
}
```

I want to make the assertion on runtimeStatus equals Completed.

Following code is not working:

```js
cy.intercept('https://api-stg.geneplanet.com/api/nipt-exporters/tasks/*/status').as('exp')
cy.get('.col-sm-12').should('be.visible').and('contain','Export').click()
cy.get('.ng-star-inserted > .p-4 > .mb-2').should('be.visible').and('contain','N2D Statistics export')
cy.get('.ng-star-inserted > .p-4 > .mb-2').should('be.visible').and('contain',' Preparing a document. Please wait.')
cy.wait('@exp').its('response.runtimeStatus').should('eq', 'Completed')
```

I've also tried should('include') and should('contain') in the last line.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Hi. Could you please assign the tracelog from the cypress client as well? the error message returned with the description. Also, will be great to see the subject yielded by `cy.wait('@exp')`. It might happen, that your response is wrapped in an additional parameter, like `data` or something else, so the path to your key might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The `cy.wait('@exp')` yields an interception object, see [Using the yielded object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-yielded-object)

```js
// interception object
{
  request: {...},
  response: {
    headers: {...},
    body: {
      "name": "ExportN2DStatisticsOrchestrator",
      "instanceId": "407ff05afdec42caa17a660d2c855117",
      "runtimeStatus": "Completed",
      ...
}
```

so this should work

```js
cy.wait('@exp').its('response.body.runtimeStatus').should('eq', 'Completed')
```

or

```js
cy.wait('@exp').its('response.body').should('have.property', '.runtimeStatus', 'Completed')
```

Comment: For both options I get error: Your page did notfire its load event within 60000s. But the page has run ok.

Comment: Yeah that's obviously something else, to do with the page load.

Comment: I did have a typo above, but that wouldn't cause the problem you stated.

Comment: @Fody - Your code shows how to check only one thing (well two properties). How do we check multiple things in the response body? like should have abc, should contain xyz?

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting http call and returning customised response

Intercepted request needs to be resolved [using the yielded object](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-yielded-object)

Cypress version: "^11.0.1"

```js
 cy.intercept(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: <API_ENDPOINT>
      },
      {
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'Success',
        body: <BODY_RESPONSE_TO_SEND_BACK>
      }
    ).as('interceptedRequest');


    cy.wait('@interceptedRequest').should(({ request, response }) => {
      cy.log("Response", response.body);

      // Perform Assertion based on response body 
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

As said by Alex on comment to your question, try below code in order to check what is inside the "intercept" object returned from the wait call:

```
cy.wait('@exp').then((intercept)=>{
    console.log(intercept); //will log a cy object containing the response
    console.log(intercept.response.runtimeStatus); //will log what you need
    expect(intercept.response.runtimeStatus).to.be.eq('Completed'); //should work
})
```

Comment: From Visual Studio Code I get: Object is possibly 'undefined' and Property 'runetimeStatus' does not exist on type 'IncomingResponse'